# Не корректная работа модальных окон

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужна помощь, не отображаются модальные окна.
Нужно открыть модальное окно, это работает. 
Потом нужно закрыть модальное окно, и отобразить новое модальное окно, которое нужно закрыть.

Как должно работать, Открывается модальное окно, Затем но нажатию кнопки модальное окно закрыватеся (с замедлением fadeOut()), Затем открывается другое модальное окно, тоже медленно из размытого в явное. После чего оно плавно затухает.

Код:

```js
(function($, undefined) {
  $(function() {

    $('#Phone').click(function() {
      $('#FerstModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('#send').click(
      function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "ajax.php",
          data: {
            name: $("#inputName").val(),
            phone: $("#inputPhone").val()
          },
          type: 'POST',
          cache: false,
          beforesend: (presend()),
          success: (function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
              $('#FerstModal').modal('hide');
            }, 2000);
          })
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#Senks').modal('show');
        }, 3000);

        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#Senks').modal('hide');
        }, 3000);

      });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: У вас `$('#Senks')` открывается через 3 секунды. И через 3 секунды закрывается. Так надо?

Comment: Мне нужно открыть одно модальное окно, в нем форма, нажимаю на кнопку отправить, далее должно, закрыться модальное окно, открыться новое и через время закрыться. Код Ссылка пример. Все приветствуется.

Comment: Ну вы внимательно на свой код посмотрите. Вы открываете модальное окно `#Senks` через 3 секунды после нажатия на кнопку, а также через 3 секунды его закрываете. Так оно должно работать? А еще лучше, в вопрос напишите, как оно должно работать. Максимально подробно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте попробуем вот так.

```js
(function($, undefined) {
  $(function() {

    $('#Phone').click(function() {
      $('#FerstModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('#send').click(
      function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "ajax.php",
          data: {
            name: $("#inputName").val(),
            phone: $("#inputPhone").val()
          },
          type: 'POST',
          cache: false,
          beforesend: (presend()),
          success: (function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
              $('#FerstModal').modal('hide');
              $('#Senks').modal('show');
              setTimeout(function() {
                $('#Senks').modal('hide');
              }, 3000);
            }, 2000);
          })
        });
      });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Второе модальное окно не появляется.

Comment: Убрал setTimeout(function(){ трали вали},2000); Заработало. А можно затухания прикрутить  fadeOut() и как?

Comment: Теперь далее Почему когда я с данными передаю Не работает  подключение второго модального окна, а просто по кнопки событие отрабатываю Все гут?

Comment: @ДимаПерильман а это уже другой совсем вопрос. И надо задавать его как новый вопрос. Если мой ответ вас устроил, пожалуйста примите его.

Comment: Я конечно глубоко заблуждаюсь но надеюсь вы меня сможете просветить. КАк же так сделать?

Comment: @ДимаПерильман создайте новый вопрос, где опишите вашу проблему.

Comment: Мне нужна быстрая подсказка пото му что проблема скорее в алготриме действий.

Comment: @ДимаПерильман Нет, проблема в том, что вы слабо разбираетесь в том, что происходит в коде. В коде, который написан скорее всего не вами. Поэтому вам нужен будет развернутый ответ. А для получения развернутого ответа, надо задать вопрос.

Comment: @ Stepan Kasyanenko Что так сложно было сказать что  ajax событие success не нужно?

Comment: @ДимаПерильман понимаете, я не могу сказать, что вам надо, пока вы ХОРОШО не объясните, что вам надо. Почему событие `success` не нужно?